# How to make testcafe work with absolute imports?

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a create react app 3 project,

so I have in my src folders some js scripts using like:

```
import { Foo } from 'components/layout/Foo
```

Unfortunately, the testcafe compiler complains about it by default.
I read that maybe the solution was to create specify a custom tsconfig.json in which I declare

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl: "src"
  }
}
```

But it does not work, apparently.
Thanks.

Comment: It looks a bit strange that your TestCafe tests reference a layout component. Please provide the exact text of the error you are facing.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, indeed it is not a component file, but a utils one in the src directory.

in my foo_test.js I have

```
import { ROOT_PATH } from '../src/utils/config'

fixture("00 Home | Arriving to the Home").page(ROOT_PATH)

test('Default | leads to the home page', async t => {
    const location = await t.eval(() => window.location)
    await t.expect(location.pathname).eql('/home')
})
```

where utils/config is

```
import { getMobileOperatingSystem } from 'utils/mobile'

export const MOBILE_OS = getMobileOperatingSystem()

let CALC_ROOT_PATH
if (MOBILE_OS === 'ios') {
   document.body.className += ' cordova-ios'
   CALC_ROOT_PATH = window.location.href.match(/file:\/\/(.*)\/www/)[0]
}

export const ROOT_PATH = CALC_ROOT_PATH || 'http://localhost:3000/'
```

Comment: As I can see, your project is written on JavasScript and that's why the `tsconfig.json` file doesn't work. A `jsconfig.json` file will not work either because TestCafe doesn't take it into account when it compiles tests. The only way to make your test work for now is to make the path in the import statement relative:
```js
import { getMobileOperatingSystem } from './mobile'
```

Comment: @aleks-pro, is there any intention for TestCafe to handle absolute imports, in the future?